# "Show in folder" error in Chrome

Tags: 16.04, google-chrome, directory

I'm using Ubuntu 16.04 and Chrome version 58. Everytime I download a file in a specific folder, say "/home/yannick/Desktop" and I click on "Show in folder", the correct folder opens but I'll get an error message that says "Could not find "/home/yannick/Desktop/Documents". Please check the spelling and try again.".

And this happens every time, wherever I save a file, when I try to "show in folder" it tries to open that folder and adds "/Documents" to the path, why would it do that?? Any ideas on how to fix this?

Thanks!

Comment: Check this solution here: https://ubuntuforums.org/showthread.php?t=1499046

Comment: Thank you, I just found out how to fix it and where the problem was coming from. My file manager is Nemo and I had created a .desktop file named "nemo.desktop" locked to the launcher to always open in the Documents folder, and  for some reason, it's like if Chrome was calling that .desktop file to open its downloaded files (so it always tried to add "/documents" to every path). So I just renamed the desktop file to "mynemo.desktop" and now everything works fine.